# What is a "slug"?

Tags: encoding

I am attempting to upload some emoticons to a particular site. The mandatory fields are:

Shortcut:

Image:

Category:

Suggested Category:

For the image, I just choose it from my file. Category fields are explanatory. I was trying to enter a web url as the "shortcut", and get this error:

"Enter a valid 'slug' consisting of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens"

I need to know what a "slug" is and how to create/get one.

Comment: This may be specific to the site; you haven't given enough to go on to know what "slug" means in this context, and you may be better off contacting the admins of the site you're using than posting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

A slug is a human-readable portion of a URL, which identifies it to the viewer.  Here is the explanation from the [Wikis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug):

> Some systems define a slug as the part of a URL which identifies a page using human-readable keywords.

For example, the slug for this post is: "what-is-a-slug".

They are probably asking for a description, such as "a-description-of-my-awesome-new-emoticon" or "confused-face".

Comment: Whilst awaiting a response from someone, I googled 'how to make a slug, and low and behold I found an online slug generator...problem solved.  Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Hah--there's an app for that!  Who knew.

Comment: @SarahChadwell, Consider accepting the answer by clicking the check button under voting button if this answer helped you. Pointing it since you are a new user.

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal identifier that will be used in url's.

For example http://url.com/category-slug/my-post